# C#, visual studio code, debugger, Error processing variables request. Unknown Error: 0x80131502

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, c#-devkit

I am using visual studio code and C# DevKit (v 1.0.12 ) and (v0.5.150).
I am not able to debug my xunit tests.
an example of my tests :

```
[Fact]
public async Task Shoud_Do_Something()
{
    var a = 5;
    var b = 6;
    var c = a + b;
}
```

and the error is shown here :

[image]

and for my csproj file code is here

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="6.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="6.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="6.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="6.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables"
      Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xunit.DependencyInjection" Version="8.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Does any one got the same issue ?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using Visual studio code :**

The issue was simply due to the length of the path of the csporj file,  the path has exceeded 256 characters.
I justed renamed the csproj files and it worked fine.

**Using Visual studio :**

If you use viusal studio for tests, this will not work even if you update the longpath property in the registery database as it is dowing its own validation

Comment: Don't you just love this hangover from older versions of Windows!